# Not iterating through whole dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So basically, I have an api from which i have several dictionaries/arrays. (http://dev.c0l.in:5984/income_statements/_all_docs)
When getting the financial information for each company from the api (e.g. sector = technology and statement = income) python is supposed to return 614 technology companies, however i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samuel\Desktop\Python Project\Mastercopy.py", line 83, in <module>
    user_input1()
  File "C:\Users\samuel\Desktop\Python Project\Mastercopy.py", line 75, in user_input1
    income_statement_fn()
  File "C:\Users\samuel\Desktop\Python Project\Mastercopy.py", line 51, in income_statement_fn
    if is_response ['sector'] == user_input3:
KeyError: 'sector'
```

on a random company (usually on one of the 550-600th ones)

Here is the function for income statements

```
def income_statement_fn():
    user_input3 = raw_input("Which sector would you like to iterate through in Income Statement?: ")
    print 'Starting...'
    for item in income_response['rows']:
        is_url = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/income_statements/" + item['id']
        is_request = urllib2.urlopen(is_url).read()
        is_response = json.loads(is_request)
        if is_response ['sector'] == user_input3:
            csv.writerow([
             is_response['company']['name'],
             is_response['company']['sales'],
             is_response['company']['opening_stock'],
             is_response['company']['purchases'],
             is_response['company']['closing_stock'],
             is_response['company']['expenses'],
             is_response['company']['interest_payable'],
             is_response['company']['interest_receivable']])
            print 'loading...'
    print 'done!'
    print end - start
```

Any idea what could be causing this error? 
(I don't believe that it is the api itself)

Cheers

Comment: There might be entries in your is_response that is not similar to the rest of your entries, which is why you probably get the keyerror. You should check if the key 'sector' is in the dictionary, and as a debugging tool you can print the is_response if sector is not a key in it. This way you can process all entries with that key, and see what entries does not have it, and what keys they have instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the final row of your `income_response` data

```
{"id":"_design/auth","key":"_design/auth","value":{"rev":"1-3d8f282ec7c26779194caf1d62114dc7"}}
```

This does not have a `sector` value. You need to alter your code to handle this line, for example by ignoring any line where the `sector` key is not present.

You could easily have debugged this with a few print statements - for example insert

```
print item['id'], is_response.get('sector', None)
```

into your code before the part that outputs the CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Well, on testing the url you pass in the `urlopen` call, with a random number, I got this:

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

In that case, your function will return exactly the error you get. If you want your program to handle the error nicely and add a "missing" line instead of actual data, you could do that for instance:

```
def income_statement_fn():
    user_input3 = raw_input("Which sector would you like to iterate through in Income Statement?: ")
    print 'Starting...'
    for item in income_response['rows']:
        is_url = "http://dev.c0l.in:5984/income_statements/" + item['id']
        is_request = urllib2.urlopen(is_url).read()
        is_response = json.loads(is_request)
        if is_response.get('sector', False) == user_input3:
            csv.writerow([
             is_response['company']['name'],
             is_response['company']['sales'],
             is_response['company']['opening_stock'],
             is_response['company']['purchases'],
             is_response['company']['closing_stock'],
             is_response['company']['expenses'],
             is_response['company']['interest_payable'],
             is_response['company']['interest_receivable']])
            print 'loading...'
        else:
            csv.writerow(['missing data'])
    print 'done!'
    print end - start
```

Comment: where is the random number coming from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham from nowhere, I tried to call the url with something that would return an error to see what the api would return.

Comment: It's not an error per-say.. it seems to be that the script does not retrieve that data at a certain point... the data is there, and it is assigned to the value "sector". .. Would it be easier to post some more of my script?

Comment: @SamuelHarrison it might be, yes

Comment: @Jivan Unfortunately i do not have a high enough reputation to post more than two links, is there anyway i can send you a copy of my code?

Answer (score 0):

A `KeyError` means that the key you tried to use does not exist in the dictionary. When checking for a key, it is much safer to use `.get()`. So you would replace this line:

```
if is_response['sector'] == user_input3:
```

With this:

```
if is_response.get('sector') == user_input3:
```

Comment: That does not answer his question. you should put this in the comments

Comment: technically None can be a value so checking if the key is in the dict would be  better solution.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, `None` is technically not possible in JSON-decoded results (and even if it were, in this program's context, a "stock with no sector" should be skipped anyway), so the double work of checking for key presence then extracting the corresponding value would **not** be a better solution here.

Comment: @AlexMartelli, I am talking about comparing to another value not the value returned from the json dict, if the key does not exist the the value will be None, it is possible that a value you are comparing it against is None so in a general sense checking for the key is a better solution in my opinion. Either way this does not answer the question.